# QTSPIM telling me c.gt.s $f0, $f1 has syntax error (pointing to .s)

Tags: mips, qtspim

This is my code, and at c.gt.s $f0, $f1 there is a syntax error pointing to the s, but it's a single precision floating point number so it needs to be c.gt.s. What am I doing wrong here?

```
.data 

numA: .float 10.5
numB: .float 12.3

.text
.globl main
main:
    la $t0, numA
    la $t1, numB
    lwc1 $f0, 0($t0)
    lwc1 $f1, 0($t1)
    c.gt.s $f0, $f1
    bc1t swap
    li $v0, 10
    syscall

swap:
    swc1 $f0, 0($f3) #f3 is temp
    swc1 $f1, 0($f0)
    swc1 $f3, 0($f0)
    jr $ra
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. Not sure why c.gt.s didnt work, but c.lt.s does and lwc1 and swc1 had to be swapped with l.s and mov.s, respectively.

```
.data 

numA: .float 12.5
numB: .float 10.3

.text
main:
    l.s $f0, numA
    l.s $f1, numB
    c.lt.s $f1, $f0
    bc1t swap
    li $v0, 10
    syscall

swap:
    mov.s $f3, $f0 #f3 is temp
    mov.s $f0 $f1
    mov.s $f1, $f3
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

Comment: There's no `GT` condition for floating-point comparisons. There's `NGT` which can combined with `BC1F` to do a "Branch if Grater Than".